# How can I apply one of my resources by name in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform will try to deploy all resources defined on Terraform configuration files. There are a lot of resources in my application, like `lmabda`, `api gateway`, `ECS` etc. I wonder whether I can specify deploying only one resource. For example, I want to deploy one `lambda` only and don't want to apply other resources. How can I make it in Terraform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`terraform apply -target=aws_lambda_function.test_function`

More information on the usage of `-target` can be found in the [terraform apply documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html#target-resource).